# Concat string to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image][image]I have a array called `tableData`, which has two elements inside it `tableData[0]` and `tableData[1]`. So I am accessing one of the column of `tableData[1]` like so

`tableData[1][0].id , tableData[1][1].foo , tableData[1][2].bar` and the list goes on.

But I don't want to hardcode it. The names id,foo,bar is in the `tableData[0]` that is actually all the heading of the columns and The `tableData[1]` has it's corresponding values.  so I want to so something like this

`tableData[1][0].tableData[0][1]`
But doing this for some weird reason say error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and I also tried this

```
var a = tableData[0][1].COLUMN_NAME
tableData[1][0].+a
```

But this is not possible? It says syntax error! How can I access the varible without hard-coding it.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the tableData variable so we can see it's formatting?

Comment: give me a second!

Comment: I think you want `tableData[1][0][tableData[0][1]]`.

Comment: use `[]` object notation

Comment: check out the content of the array @mikeg542

Comment: With that content, then e.g. `tableData[1][0][tableData[0][1].COLUMN_NAME]`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Solved it. Can someone please explain without `.` it works and `.` gives me error? @charlietfl @smarx

Comment: The question this has been marked a duplicate of is probably the right place to learn more.